# List view webpart JS Link is not working - Sharepoint 2013

Tags: listview, user-interface, web-parts, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to render the UI of list view webpart using JS Link option in SharePoint 2013. I uploaded the colorcode_items_script.JS file to masterpagegallary as 'JavaScript Display Template' content type. gave 'Target Control Type' as 'form', 'Standalone' as 'override' 'Target Scope' as '/', 'Target List Template ID' as '100'. created a 'Sales' list using OOB Custom list template. Added the list view webpart instance to a page and pointed the 'JS Link' to uploaded 'colorcode_items_script.JS' file as per [this](http://mosshosting.asphostportal.com/?p=2754) article 
But the color coded rendering is not happening and I am getting OOB list view webpart display only. Am I missing anything?

Comment: I haven't made any changes and strangely, it started working on next day.

Comment: Lol, i hope tomorrow my jslink works :)